# PUT operation saves data in wrong way JSON WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, json, json.net

I try to do a PUT operation by passing a set of JSON Data to server from WPF application and i used Newtonsoft for doing it. 
The Newtonsoft JObject returns proper JSON format for me with required data and PUT operation is also successful , but after updating the data i can see the changes are not reflected completely on Server
The code i used to generate JSON of the structre like this http://pastebin.com/hQPMm79H is

```
JArray book_pref_val_root = new JArray();

JObject val_item;
JObject val_set;
JArray book_array;
string bookid = "";

//start of item 1
val_item = new JObject();

bookid = "52b020fda47ab2e07f000003";
val_item.Add(new JProperty("id", bookid));

book_array = new JArray();

val_set = new JObject();
val_set.Add(new JProperty("name", "key1"));
val_set.Add(new JProperty("value", 1));
book_array.Add(val_set);

val_set = new JObject();
val_set.Add(new JProperty("name", "key2"));
val_set.Add(new JProperty("value", 0));
book_array.Add(val_set);

val_set = new JObject();
val_set.Add(new JProperty("name", "key3"));
val_set.Add(new JProperty("value", 0.5));
book_array.Add(val_set);

val_item.Add(new JProperty("params", book_array));
//END of item 1

book_pref_val_root.Add(val_item);

//satrt of itm2
val_item = new JObject();

bookid = "522efc12cfe1c4a56e000005";
val_item.Add(new JProperty("id", bookid));

book_array = new JArray();

val_set = new JObject();
val_set.Add(new JProperty("name", "key1"));
val_set.Add(new JProperty("value", 1));
book_array.Add(val_set);

val_set = new JObject();
val_set.Add(new JProperty("name", "Key2"));
val_set.Add(new JProperty("value", .4));
book_array.Add(val_set);

val_item.Add(new JProperty("params", book_array));

//end of itm2

book_pref_val_root.Add(val_item);


JArray pref_root = new JArray();

JObject pref_item = new JObject();
pref_item.Add(new JProperty("name", "books"));
pref_item.Add(new JProperty("value", book_pref_val_root));
pref_root.Add(pref_item);

pref_item = new JObject();
pref_item.Add(new JProperty("name", "language"));
pref_item.Add(new JProperty("value", "en_US"));
pref_root.Add(pref_item);

pref_item = new JObject();
pref_item.Add(new JProperty("name", "app_zoom"));
pref_item.Add(new JProperty("value", 1));
pref_root.Add(pref_item);

JObject root_object = new JObject();
root_object.Add(new JProperty("token", "sadssad"));
root_object.Add(new JProperty("preferences", pref_root));
string json_string = root_object.ToString();
```

And the output JSON format is here

```
"token": "sadssad",
"preferences": [{
"name": "books",
"value": [{
    "id": "52b020fda47ab2e07f000003",
    "params": [{
        "name": "key1",
        "value": 1
    }, {
        "name": "key2",
        "value": 0
    }, {
        "name": "key3",
        "value": 0.5
    }]
}, {
    "id": "522efc12cfe1c4a56e000005",
    "params": [{
        "name": "key1",
        "value": 1
    }, {
        "name": "key2",
        "value": 0.4
    }]
}]
}, {
"name": "language",
"value": "en_US"
}, {
"name": "app_zoom",
"value": 1
}]
```

Now i do PUT operation on server using this code

```
 var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url_toPUT);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";
            using (var streamWriter = new   StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(json_string);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
                {
                    bool actionStatus = true; 
                }
            }
```

And the PUT operation is also successful . But problem for me is after PUT operation when i check data on remote server i can see the preferences is saved as

```
"preferences":[{"name":"books","value":"[object Object],[object Object]"},{"name":"language","value":"en_US"},{"name":"app_zoom","value":"1"}]
```

as here can see that value for books parameter is just of type [object object] . 
Whats the problem happens while PUT data ? Any suggestions?

Comment: is there any error message? also seems like it has nothing to do with WPF.

Comment: There is no error message PUT operation is successful . But when i cross check data it shows the value as an object array [object object] not as the values